# Is it safe to access a service class within a Observer spring bean located at src/java

Tags: grails, thread-safety, grails-orm

I have this class, it is inside a grails plugin we developed at work, it is an HttpSessionListener
and I don't have direct access to its source code from our application:

This class catches the session destroyed event and notifies its observers, passing destroyed session as parameter.

```
//import statements ommited for brevity
public class ContextListener extends Observable implements HttpSessionListener{
    private static ContextListener instance;

    public ContextListener() {
        instance = this;
    }


    public static ContextListener instance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public void sessionCreated(final HttpSessionEvent event) {}

    public void sessionDestroyed(final HttpSessionEvent event) {
        HttpSession session = event.getSession();
        setChanged();
        notifyObservers(session);
    }
}
```

Now, I have implemented an observer in src/java, this observer will Observe the ContextListener instance and then 
call a service method and will pass the object retrieved from update event as parameter.

```
import java.util.Observer;
import java.util.Observable;

public class SessionObserver implements Observer{
    private MyService myService;

    public SessionObserver(){
        //Register this as an observer of ContextListener instance
        ContextListener.instance().addObserver(this);
    }

    public void update(Observable o, Object arg){
        //should this be wrapped inside a synchronized(this) block?
        //logSessionDestroyed will have access to database
        myService.logSessionDestroyed(arg);
    }

    public void setMyService(MyService myService){
        this.myService = myService;
    }

    public MyService getMyService(){
        return this.myService;
    }
}
```

By the way, SessionObserver is created at conf/spring/resources.groovy, and myService is injected successfully.

```
beans = {
    sessionObserver(SessionObserver){
        myService = ref("myService");
    }
}
```

myService.logSessionDestroyed() will write to database, is the access to the service method
concurrent-safe? or should it be wrapped inside a synchronized(this) block?

And what About ContextListener's sessionDestroyed event? should it be synchronized too?

Additional info: Grails version used: 2.5.0